# GKE - Auto repairing after adding a new nodepool

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

The GKE is auto repairing after the addition of a new nodepool. The nodepool size is 1. Machine type n1-standard-64. It's being in that repaired state for almost 30 min. No other cluster operation can be performed until the repair is done.

Please help me out if any of you faced a similar issue and resolved it.

[image: Screenshot of the repair info on the cluster page]

Comment: How many other nodepools do you have?
Is this a zonal or regional cluster?
What is the output of `kubectl get nodes`?

Comment: 1.  I have 7 nodepools in total, but faced a similar issue while adding each nodepool, right from the second nodepool. 
2. It's a zonal cluster.
3. kubectl get nodes - displays previously added nodes.

Answer (score 2):

well the reason why GKE starts auto-repairing a node, is because detected that your nodes are in a unhealthy state for a given time threshold.
unhealthy state could mean:

- A node reports a NotReady status on consecutive checks over the given
  time threshold (approximately 10 minutes).
- A node does not report any status at all over the given time
  threshold (approximately 10 minutes).
- A node's boot disk is out of disk space for an extended time period
  (approximately 30 minutes).

If GKE detects that a node requires repair, the node is drained and re-created. **GKE waits one hour for the drain to complete.** If the drain doesn't complete, the node is shut down and a new node is created.

You can always review the logs of the repairing nodes, to find what is the root cause.

And you can always disable auto-repairing, by running this lines in cloud shell or check the console instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair#disable)

gcloud container node-pools update *pool-name* --cluster *cluster-name* 
--zone *compute-zone* 
--no-enable-autorepair